# Is there a way to run a regression with both characters and integers?

Tags: r, large-data

I am trying to run regression on a really large data set from IPUMS, but I am having a hard time doing anything with the data because it includes both integers and characters. Additionally, I am wondering if there is a way to select random observations from this dataset to make it much more usable as it currently has 2.5 million observations.

I have tried to run `as.factor` on everything in the dataset, but I can't get a usable result for the `lm()` of the data.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(modelr)
library(haven)
library(ipumsr)
ddi <- read_ipums_ddi("usa_00006.xml")
data <- read_ipums_micro(ddi)
elderly <- as_tibble(data)
elderly <- filter(elderly, AGE >= 65)
elderly <- filter(elderly, YEAR > 2017)
elderly <- select(elderly, YEAR, PERWT, SEX, AGE, MARST, RACE, BPL, EDUC, EMPSTAT, INCWAGE, INCSS, INCRETIR, OFFPOV)
elderly <- mutate(elderly, INCTOTAL = INCSS + INCWAGE + INCRETIR)
elderly2 <- mutate(elderly, across(everything(), as.factor))
```

This is what I have tried, because to filter anything for N/A results before running the `as.factor` it returns this error.

```
> elderly <- filter(elderly, OFFPOV !="NA")
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = OFFPOV != "NA"`.
Caused by error in `vec_equal()`:
! Can't combine `..1` <character> and `..2` <integer>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I am at a loss of how to manipulate this dataset to be usable, so anything would help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: try `filter(elderly, !is.na(OFFPOV))` if you want to exclude `NA` values, which are different from the text "NA".

Answer (score 1):

- Converting *everything* into a factor is probably a mistake.
- use `na.omit()` or `filter(!is.na(...))` or `drop_na()` to get rid of NA values, not `. == "NA"` or `. == NA`
- in fact, most R modeling tools will convert characters to factors on the fly for you, although doing so explicitly is a good idea
- use `slice_sample()` to subset randomly

  - if you're OK with a *non-random* sample you could probably speed things up by setting `n_max` when you read in the data in the first place

You probably want something like:

```r
elderly <- (read_ipums_micro(ddi)
   ## don't need as_tibble(): already returns a tbl_df
   ## take a random 10% sample
   |> slice_sample(prop = 0.1)
   |> filter(AGE >= 65, Year > 2017)
   |> mutate(across(where(is.character), factor))
   |> select(c(YEAR, PERWT, SEX, AGE, MARST, 
               RACE, BPL, EDUC, EMPSTAT, INCWAGE, INCSS, 
               INCRETIR, OFFPOV))
   |> drop_na(everything())
   |> mutate(INCTOTAL = INCSS + INCWAGE + INCRETIR)
)
```